# How to print nothing in else statement of ifelse in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame `A` in which I want to search for a value `300` in `A$product_id`. I have `b<-300`. Now I use `ifelse(A$product_id%in%b,print("Yes"),print(""))` but I get a lot of "" as output when `A$product_id!=300` instead of blank space. I only want it to print yes when `A$product_id==300` otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `NULL`, but the main question is why you want to do this?

You could also use something like `which( A$product_id < 300 )` or something like that if you want to locate which `id`s are small.

Answer (score 1):

below one should work, no need to use print function

```
as.character(ifelse(A$prduct_id %in% b, "Yes", ""))
```